# How can I increment over a field using sql?

Tags: php, sql

***Here's my DB***

[image]

All I want to do is to reset all of the fields with a specific `stranica_id` to 1 and increment them as I go down the list.

***This would be the desired output.***

[image]

so that every column with a specific value gets incremented if it occurs more than once.

I tried this:

```
SET @count = 0; UPDATE `events` SET `events`.`tablica_id` = @count:= @count + 1;
```

but it only works if I execute it in phpmyadmin and doesn't work if I execute it with php.
Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

**NOTE:** The type of field that I'm trying to change is INT (integer), and it **doesn't** auto-increment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using mysqli connection for this than you should use multi_query to achieve your task

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'dbUser', 'dbPass', 'dbName');

$sql = 'SET @count = 0;';
$sql .= 'UPDATE `events` SET `events`.`tablica_id` = @count:= @count + 1;';

$mysqli->multi_query($sql);
```

Comment: edited my answer as I forgot to put .(dot) under second $sql statement we need to concatenate the queries and than execute them

Comment: I have tried this under my local system on another table which I have created for sample and it is working.